# isMovableByWindowBackground for SwiftUI MacCatalyst

Tags: swiftui, nswindow, mac-catalyst

How could I access attributes from NSWindow for a SwiftUI Catalyst app? For example, allowing moving a window by dragging its background via NSWindow.moveableByWindowBackground.

I'm specifying the basics already in **SceneDelegate.swift**.

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let app = UIApplication.shared
        let delegate = app.delegate as! AppDelegate
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
                titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
                titlebar.toolbar = nil
            }
            if let sizeRestrictions = windowScene.sizeRestrictions {
                sizeRestrictions.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1300, height: 800)
            }
            window.canResizeToFitContent = true
            #endif

            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: GreatHallView(screenerVM: delegate.screenerVM).environmentObject(SortingHat()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need the **Dynamic** [library](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic.git) from Mhd Hejazi.  It can be included in your code with SPM.

Next, an extension to UIWindow:

```
    extension UIWindow {
        var nsWindow: NSObject? {
            Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(self)
        }
    }
```

Now you can associate the NSWindow with the UIWindow and call methods and extract properties as follow:

```
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    let ns = window.nsWindow
    let frame = Dynamic(ns!).frame.asCGRect!
    let size = frame.size
    Dynamic(ns!).setAspectRatio(CGSize(1.0, size.height/size.width))
    print(Dynamic(ns!).isMovableByWindowBackground.asBool!)
    Dynamic(ns!).setMovableByWindowBackground(true)
    print(Dynamic(ns!).isMovableByWindowBackground.asBool!)
    #endif
```

Remember to import Dynamic were needed.  Also, use the Object-C methods and properties, not Swift.